# cmd or powershell command from html with no window

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

is there a way to active a powershell or a cmd command from html file without opening a console window ?
for example the following code runs the l.bat file i have without showing the output but still there is a powershell window which is open while the file runs

code:

```
<OBJECT id=z classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11" width=5 height=5>
<PARAM name="Command" value="ShortCut">
<PARAM name="Button" value="Bitmap::shortcut">
<PARAM name="Item1" value=",powershell.exe ,Start-Process &#45WindowStyle hidden 'l'">
</OBJECT>
```

any idea?

Comment: From the security matters, I HIGHLY DOUBT that would be possible. It would surely open many backdoors if it was possible, and till now I didn't even know about being able to run a bat file using HTML like that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want run script or bat file in html file or in ur site want run script 
you can use visual studio and add  Web Application called PowerShellExecution
default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PowerShellExecution.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><h1 align="left">PowerShell Command Harness</h1></td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>PowerShell Command</td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <br />
                </td><td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Input" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="433px" Height="73px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                &nbsp;</td><td>
                <asp:Button ID="ExecuteCode" runat="server" Text="Execute" Width="200" onclick="ExecuteCode_Click" />
            </td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><h3>Result</h3></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    &nbsp;</td><td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ResultBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="700" Height="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tools menu select Library Package Manager >> Package Manager Console
Package Manager Console execute “Install-Package System.Management.Automation”
After a successful execution of that package install, you’ll want to add the reference to your Default.aspx.cs file:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

in ur Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;

namespace PowerShellExecution
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clean the Result TextBox
            ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

            // Initialize PowerShell engine
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();

            // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);

            // Execute the script
            var results = shell.Invoke();

            // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
            // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                // We use a string builder ton create our result text
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                    // Add \r\n for line breaks
                    builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }

                // Encode the string in HTML (prevent security issue with 'dangerous' caracters like < >
                ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

“PowerShell Command” window Get-EventLog Security -Newest 10 (or your favorite cmdlet for a test).
or put script on that just change

```
//shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);
shell.Commands.AddScript("C:\\Scripts\\PowerShell\\PowerShellScript.ps1")
```

but for run script you should run
Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
in your powershell 32 bit and 64 bit
64 bit

```
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

32 bit

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

you should run visual studio and publish in your iis very simple to add feature iis
for dns you can use

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

in host file like

```
127.0.0.1 soheil.com
```

I hope i understand ur needs
Regards